# Admob in Android Fragment

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments, admob, android-dialogfragment

I am unable to place AdMob in ActionBarSherlock Fragment. Since in Activity the ActionBar won't allow to display the xml layout but the xml file is referenced in the fragment class.

I am running into errors? How can I place AdMob into fragment class.